# URL Rewrite not working on localhost in ubuntu

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, localhost

So i'm running lampp on ubuntu 11.10 and i have the following problem

i need this url:
localhost/myname/oefeningenPHP/cms/index.php?head=about

rewritten to:
localhost/myname/oefeningenPHP/cms/about

The url is kinda messy because i have lots of folder with different PHP exercises for school.

My .htacces is located in:
localhost/myname/oefeningenPHP/cms

since cms is my sites root.

.htacces contains the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/([a-z]+) /index.php?head=$1 

</IfModule>
```

But returns a 404 error.

Furthermore i'm sure the rewrite module is being loaded since it's uncommented in the http.conf file

I've ran out of ideas so i'm hoping someone here can help me. I'm not very sure about the forward slashes in the RewriteRule, but i've tried various things and nothing works

Comment: The regex simply don't match the url

Comment: delete the <IfModule mod_rewrite.c> and </IfModule> tags. they are useless. if it gives a 500 error, you don't have url rewrite activated.

Comment: De slash aan het begin van de expressie moet je weglaten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+) index.php?head=$1 [L]
```

You should also see if you .htaccess is enabled by adding some junk to it e.g. `asdfasdfasdfasd`, save it and try to access the URL. If you do not get a 500 error, then it is not enabled.

To enable it look for a line that says

```
AllowOverride None
```

and change it to

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: Without the slashes it gets past the erver errors, but now i get some php errors. Is this because the get parameters arn't passed anymore?

Comment: @user1185774 I don't think so, but you can confirm by going directly to the url i.e. if `localhost/myname/oefeningenPHP/cms/index.php?head=about` gives you the same errors, then it is not related to the .htaccess rules

Answer (score 1):

If you have already run sudo a2enmod rewrite  command but your URL Rewrite is not working.
To make .htaccess files work as expected, you need to edit this file:

```
Step1 : sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

Step2 : Look for a section that looks like this: 
    <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
                # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
                #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
        </Directory>
You need to modify the line containing AllowOverride None to read AllowOverride All.
step 3 : sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```